# append newest ul and li on top every time jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I am trying to add UL and LI to DIV, Every time UL and LI is getting added at last position.

```
if (data.indexOf("ERROR") == -1) {
    var _tempUL = $('<ul/>').addClass('navlist');
    $("#divAddItem").append(_tempUL);
    var liText = $('<li/>').addClass('btn-shadow btn-gradient').html(data);
    _tempUL.append(liText);
    _tempUL.append('<li class="close"><a class="removeLi"><img src="../Images/close.png" /></a></li>');
}
```

What I want is, newest added UL LI always add/show at first position.

Comment: Use `prepend()` instead of `append()`

Comment: Try `$("#divAddItem").prepend(_tempUL);` in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the line `$("#divAddItem").append(_tempUL);` with `$("#divAddItem").prepend(_tempUL);`

Comment: Why dd anyone downrate this?

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: What is there to explain ? 
Replace the line `$("#divAddItem").append(_tempUL);` with  `$("#divAddItem").prepend(_tempUL);`

Comment: Maybe that's why the downvote. It's a question that can be answered with a simple search and needs no explanation. And by answering you're encouraging more of such bad poorly researched questions.

Comment: Well... the essence of a learning community is that those with minimal knowledge would learn from experienced ones. Some of the questions I answer today, I could have asked them 2 or 3 yrs ago! Downvoting something because it looks "trivial" is very anti-learning, I think

Comment: The community doesn't encourage users to ask the same questions solved in past over and over again. Instead it is recommended to search for existing answers first. Spoon feeding is "anti-learning" imho. Do you honestly think this was a problem that can't be **easily** solved by taking some time to search documentation/existing answers in SO/google etc...